# Redirigir a url de idioma con htaccess

Tags: redirección

Estoy trabajando con **CodeIgniter** y he implementado el **multi idioma** para agregar distintos idiomas. Todo funciona perfecto, el problema es que ahora **misitio/** y **misitio/es** tienen el mismo contenido. Quiero redirigir de **misitio/** a **misitio/es** pero no lo consigo.

Este es mi archivo htaccess actual, ahora estoy trabajando en local:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: tal vez estas ligas puedan servirte  [codeigniter_i18n](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n), [codeigniter wiki ](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n)[codeigniter home], (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter)

Comment: Seguí esa guía para implementar el multi idioma, pero no menciona nada sobre la redirección de urls. Solo habla del archivo routes, que ya tengo configurado. Todo me funciona bien, pero me falta esa redirección.

Comment: @Mathiew82 en lugar de poner la solución dentro de la pregunta en sí, lo que deberías hacer es ponerla como respuesta y marcarla como aceptada cuando puedas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado!**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /misitio/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^index.php/(es|ca)/(.{0})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.{0})$ es [R=301,L]
```

De esta forma, al acceder a la home **sin /es**, se redirige a la home **con /es**. Para el resto de páginas se utilizan los propios enlaces del sitio para acceder al idioma seleccionado.